# How to add an image from local machine to already existing layer on photoshop using javascript photoshop scripting?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript

I have an existing design and layers on photoshop and I want to add an image from my local machine to one of those layers and I don't know how to do it using a script on javascript?

please any help on this ?

Comment: Use a [Scripting Listener](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html#ScriptingListenerplugin) plugin to record cide for the File > Place command

Comment: Sorry but i'm really new on ths field i don't understand how to use it can you explain to me please? @SergeyKritskiy

Comment: The link I posted explains how to use it. If you don't understand it maybe consider hiring someone to write the code for you.